# How do I change dmenu font and size?

Tags: dmenu

How do I change the size as well as font on dmenu? Dmenu is a software launcher. It it possible to do `/usr/bin/dmenu_run -fn 'FireCode-16'`, but that changes the whole dmenu bar size, not just the font. I want the bar to be thicker, but I want to be able to make the font a a size that matches the font on my status bar.

Answer (score 1):

The [Line height](https://tools.suckless.org/dmenu/patches/line-height/) patch does exactly that. It gives you an option to customize the height of the dmenu bar:

```bash
$ dmenu_run -fn 'FiraCode-16' -h 24
```